# Django prefetch_related and select_related

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am wondering about the behaviour of prefetch_related() and select_related(). 
If I do something like Model.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(), I notice that there are much less database queries occurring. So my initial guess is that, if one does not specify the needed look-ups in prefetch_related(), it will automatically go through all of the model fields and do the needed job. However, I cannot find any reference to it on the web, which seems pretty strange to me. Is my guess correct or am I missing something?

Comment: This question is not clear. What can't you find any reference to? What behaviour is surprising you?

Comment: Basically, when calling select_related() with no arguments, does django apply it to all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the FineManual(tm)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) (emphasis is mine):

> There may be some situations where you wish to call select_related()
>   with a lot of related objects, or where you don’t know all of the
>   relations. **In these cases it is possible to call select_related() with
>   no arguments**. This will follow all non-null foreign keys it can find -
>   nullable foreign keys must be specified. This is not recommended in
>   most cases as it is likely to make the underlying query more complex,
>   and return more data, than is actually needed.